# Querying child properties

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to copy my index over but skipping a property when it matches a specific value. I found out how to exclude a property all together, but I need something like this:

`exclude 'terms property' WHERE 'source_terminology subproperty' not like '%earthMaterials%`

Is this possible in ElasticSearch or should I approach it in a different way?

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source" : {
    "index" : "documents3",
    "_source":{
      "excludes": [
        "terms"   
      ]
    }
  },
  "dest" : {
    "index" : "documents4"
  }
}
```

This is a reduced version of my mapping:

```
{
  "documents4": {
    "mappings": {
      "doc": {
        "properties": {
          "abstract": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "author": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "raw": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "terms": {
            "properties": {
              "source_terminology": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                  }
                }
              },
              "uri": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is a bit how my data looks like now:

```
      {
        "_index": "documents4",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "6bf03d1e-f7dc-40c6-a32d-c9aa09e7b051",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "terms": [
            {
              "source_terminology": "exploration-activity-type",
              "label": "feasibility study",
              "uri": "http://resource.geosciml.org/classifier/cgi/exploration-activity-type/feasibility-study"
            },
                        {
              "source_terminology": "earthMaterialsAT",
              "label": "rock",
              "uri": "http://www.similarto.com/ontologies/lithology/2010/12/earthMaterialsAT#rock"
            },
            "title": "Miguel Auza Initial Prospectus"
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use painless script to add the conditions you need.

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source" : {
    "index" : "documents4"
  },
  "dest" : {
    "index" : "documents4-copy3"
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "int index = 0; def list = new ArrayList(); for(term in ctx._source.terms) { if(term.source_terminology =~ /^(?:(?!exploration).)+$/) { list.add(0, index) } index++;} for(item in list) { ctx._source.terms.remove(item)}",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

You need `script.painless.regex.enabled` value set to `true` in `elasticsearch.yml` file for this to work.

Formatted version of Painless script

```
int index = 0;
def list = new ArrayList();
for (term in ctx._source.terms) {
  if (term.source_terminology = ~ /^(?:(?!earthMaterials).)+$/) {
    // Need to add matched index at start to avoid
    // index_out_of_bounds_exception when removing items later
    list.add(0, index)
    // If you try to remove item as soon as match is found,
    // you will get concurrent_modification_exception
  }
  index++;
}
for (item in list) {
  ctx._source.terms.remove(item)
}
```

Comment: This answer is concise and is definitely taking me into the right direction. I found out as well that I will have to use Split or StringTokenizer because I'm using an AWS ES cluster. Thanks a lot!